# How to use Hammer to swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, hammer.js

I've found an interesting resource: Hammer.js. I tried to swipe with Hammer and jQuery.

1) I've downloaded the code [here](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)
2) I've put that code in a document. I put a link to that code in the head of the document I want to use swipe: `<script src="hammer.js"></script>`
3) I do not know how to use it. I try to do something similar to this in jQuery. I mean I want to swipe instead of click:

```
$(function(){
    $(".blue").click(function() {
        $(".blue").animate({left: "0"}, 500)    
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Narcis/rmtXC/

Answer (score 34):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6jxbv/119/

I'm using `Hammer(element).on("event", callback);` to get the result. In this case, I added the `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events.

The script uses the syntax described above to add events like:

```
drag, dragstart, dragend, dragup, dragdown, dragleft, dragright
swipe, swipeup, swipedown, swipeleft, swiperight
```

If you want to use it with jQuery, they provide this syntax (which is kind of awkward if you ask me):

```
$(elementOrSelector).hammer().on("event", function(event) {
    //callback
});
```

But you have to include the `jquery.hammer.js` plugin

Try reading [the docs](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) for more info

**EDIT:**

Here, you can see an example using swipe and drag. Take into account that swipe is a fast movement (with the mouse or touch) and drag is pressing and moving (so the implementation it's not correct, but I'll leave the animate to you. :) )

http://jsfiddle.net/uZjCB/183/  and full screen   http://jsfiddle.net/uZjCB/183/embedded/result/

Hope it helps

Comment: I read the docs before asking, but I am really confused, I do not understand very well. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I think your code does not work. Have you check it?

Comment: If you swipe left the squares move to the left, and if you swipe right they move to the right. What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. But I test  http://jsfiddle.net/rTFrB/ in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox and I do not see nothing moving on swipe or in any case. I do not understand?

Comment: Are you trying it in a table or in your browser with a mouse?. Try http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Bnz/embedded/result/ it's working for me in chrome with a mouse and in a ASUS tf300 tablet.

Comment: @Nrc well, in case you are confusing swipe with drag, remember that swipe is a fast movement, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uZjCB/2/ I'll edit the answer with it as well. I tested it and it's working. I hope it helps

Comment: I try to do in a desktop the usual movement that we do in phones and tablets to go to one screen to another. Is this swipe?. I try your fiddle in a iMac desktop and in a iPad, and swipe does not work. Drag does something but in a bit estrange way. Anyway, thank you very much for your eford!

Comment: I found that it's almost impossible to trigger a swipe with a mouse. You can trigger a drag, but not a swipe.

Comment: I am trying http://jsfiddle.net/uZjCB/2/embedded/result/ using iPhone 5/iOS 7.1.1/Safari and OSX 10.9.3/Safari 7.0.1 and OSX 10.9.3/Chrome 35.0.1916.114 No matter what I try I cannot get that bitch to move one pixel.

Comment: full screen example has following error `Hammer is not defined`

Comment: Hammer moved the source of the script that's why it wasn't defined properly. I updated the urls.

Comment: Hey @NicoSantangelo thanks for all your work here, does this need another update though? the drag is not giving me any changes.

Answer (score 12):

With Hammer.js 2.0 you need to use a Recognizer :

```
var blue      = document.getElementById('blue');
var hammer    = new Hammer.Manager(blue);
var swipe     = new Hammer.Swipe();

hammer.add(swipe);

hammer.on('swipeleft', function(){
   $(blue).animate({left: "-=100"}, 500)  
});

hammer.on('swiperight', function(){
   $(blue).animate({left: "+=100"}, 500)  
});
```

read more on Hammer [documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/)

Comment: I personally find hammer 2.0 complicated to implement. It blocks default events for example.

Answer (score 5):

updating the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilbertolenzi/uZjCB/208/) with correct Hammer cdn so now it's working:

```
$(function(){  
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var blue = document.getElementById("blue");

//Swipe
Hammer(red).on("swipeleft", function() {
    $(this).find(".color").animate({left: "-=100"}, 500);
    $("#event").text("swipe left");
});

Hammer(red).on("swiperight", function() {
    $(this).find(".color").animate({left: "+=100"}, 500);
    $("#event").text("swipe right");
});

// Drag
Hammer(blue).on("dragleft", function() {
    $(this).find(".color").animate({left: "-=100"}, 500);
    $("#event").text("drag left");
});

Hammer(blue).on("dragright", function() {
    $(this).find(".color").animate({left: "+=100"}, 500);
    $("#event").text("drag right");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with hammer.js v2.0.8

https://jsfiddle.net/elijah123467/q6m84wgt/6/

```
var body = $("#body");
var navbar = $("#navbar");

var hammertimeBodyRight = new Hammer.Manager(body[0], {
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT}]
    ]
});

hammertimeBodyRight.on("swipe", function (ev) {
    var canvasSlid = navbar.hasClass("canvas-slid");
    if (!canvasSlid) {
        $(".navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});

var hammertimeBodyLeft = new Hammer.Manager(body[0], {
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT}]
    ]
});

hammertimeBodyLeft.on("swipe", function (ev) {
    var canvasSlid = navbar.hasClass("canvas-slid");
    if (canvasSlid) {
        $(".navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});

var hammertimeNavbarRight = new Hammer.Manager(navbar[0], {
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT}]
    ]
});

hammertimeNavbarRight.on("swipe", function (ev) {
    var canvasSlid = navbar.hasClass("canvas-slid");
    if (!canvasSlid) {
        $(".navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});

var hammertimeNavbarLeft = new Hammer.Manager(navbar[0], {
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT}]
    ]
});

hammertimeNavbarLeft.on("swipe", function (ev) {
    var canvasSlid = navbar.hasClass("canvas-slid");
    if (canvasSlid) {
        $(".navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});
```